# XMPPFramework - How to Add Users to MUC Room

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am creating group chat app. I am able to create the group with below code.

```
_xmppRoomStorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc]init];
   XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"room1@conference.abc.biz"];
   _xmppRoom =[[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJID];
   [_xmppRoom              activate:_xmppStream];
   [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:_userNameEdit.text history:nil];
```

but now I need to add some users to this group. Can any one please let me know how to add or invite multiple users to this group.

I have one more problem. not able to create 2nd room when 1st group is active. When I try to create 2nd room it gives below error

"XMPPRoom[room2@conference.abc.biz] - Cannot create/join room when already creating/joining/joined"

Thanks.
Vaz

Comment: I have resolved this problem......

Comment: Can you share the solution i was actually facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by doing as follows:

1. Create the room first

   ```
   -(void) CreateRoom
   {
       XMPPJID *roomRealJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:jidRoom];// Room name ex. abc@conference.xyz.biz
       XMPPRoom *newXmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:[[self appDelegate] xmppRoomStorage] jid:roomRealJid    dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)];
       [newXmppRoom activate: [[self appDelegate] xmppStream]];
       [newXmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
       [newXmppRoom addDelegate:[self appDelegate] delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
       [newXmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:nickName history:nil password:[[NSUserDefaults     standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kXMPPmyPassword]];
   }
   ```
2. Send invitations

   ```
   // Once the room created, we get some responses from server. 
   // One of them is "didFetchModeratorsList".

   - (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchModeratorsList:(NSArray *)items
   {
       DDLogInfo(@"%@: %@ --- %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, sender.roomJID.bare);

       if (check the flag for room create and invite) // This has to be done only when we intended
       {
           NSArray* users = list of users we need to invite.

           if (users.count > 0)
           {
               for (int i=0; i< users.count; i++)
               {
                   NSString *jid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@xyz.biz", [users objectAtIndex:i]];
                   XMPPJID *xmppJID=[XMPPJID jidWithString:jid];
                   [sender inviteUser:xmppJID withMessage:@"Join Group."];
               }
               [sender sendMessageWithBody:@"Hi All"];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.